# SELinux permission denied to Phusion Passenger for redmine

Tags: permissions, centos, passenger, redmine, selinux

I am trying to install *Redmine* on *CentOS 6.3* but I continue to get this error in the log file

```
Passenger could not be initialized because of this error: Unable to start 
the Phusion Passenger watchdog (/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-4.0.20/buildout
 /agents/PassengerWatchdog): Permission denied (errno=13)
```

I have been looking online and cannot find this error anywhere or any way to fix it. I have tried changing permissions to the folder to `777` and `apache:apache` but neither work.

The only solution that I have come up with to get *redmine* to work is to set *SELinux* to disabled or permissive (which I do not want to do).

Does anyone have another way to fix this problem that leaves *SELinux* enabled?

Found the SELinux log file under /var/log/messages

here is the end of the file

```
    Oct 16 14:07:30 localhost pulseaudio[2329]: alsa-util.c: Disabling timer-based scheduling because running inside a VM.
    Oct 16 14:07:30 localhost rtkit-daemon[2183]: Sucessfully made thread 2331 of process 2329 (/usr/bin/pulseaudio) owned by '500' RT at priority 5.
    Oct 16 14:07:30 localhost pulseaudio[2329]: alsa-util.c: Disabling timer-based scheduling because running inside a VM.
    Oct 16 14:07:30 localhost rtkit-daemon[2183]: Sucessfully made thread 2332 of process 2329 (/usr/bin/pulseaudio) owned by '500' RT at priority 5.
    Oct 16 14:07:31 localhost rtkit-daemon[2183]: Sucessfully made thread 2427 of process 2427 (/usr/bin/pulseaudio) owned by '500' high priority at nice level -11.
    Oct 16 14:07:31 localhost pulseaudio[2427]: pid.c: Daemon already running.
    Oct 16 14:08:04 localhost kernel: type=1400 audit(1381957684.726:5): avc:  denied  { execute_no_trans } for  pid=2663 comm="httpd" path="/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-4.0.20/buildout/agents/PassengerWatchdog" dev=dm-0 ino=1048752 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:lib_t:s0 tclass=file
    Oct 16 14:08:04 localhost kernel: type=1400 audit(1381957684.760:6): avc:  denied  { execute_no_trans } for  pid=2668 comm="httpd" path="/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-4.0.20/buildout/agents/PassengerWatchdog" dev=dm-0 ino=1048752 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:lib_t:s0 tclass=file
    Oct 16 14:09:11 localhost pulseaudio[2329]: alsa-sink.c: ALSA woke us up to write new data to the device, but there was actually nothing to write!
    Oct 16 14:09:11 localhost pulseaudio[2329]: alsa-sink.c: Most likely this is a bug in the ALSA driver 'snd_intel8x0'. Please report this issue to the ALSA developers.
    Oct 16 14:09:11 localhost pulseaudio[2329]: alsa-sink.c: We were woken up with POLLOUT set -- however a subsequent snd_pcm_avail() returned 0 or another value < min_avail.
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, you can fix this by using audit2allow (yum install audit-libs-python audit-libs).

SELinux logs to /var/log/audit/audit.log. If you tail and capture the output from restarting the web service (service httpd restart) you can then run the new output through audit2allow and make a module to install under selinux...

So, assuming you have captured it into a file called "audit_tmp":

```
cat audit_tmp | audit2allow -D -M passenger
```

This will create a file called passenger.pp which you can apply using:

```
semodule -i passenger.pp
```

Doing this will unblock the first thing that was stopping passenger from loading - but be aware that there will probably be more so you will need to repeats the process again until it works. I hope that makes sense!

Comment: If you're going to go about it that way, "setenforce 0" first so that it will audit *all* of the denials that would be encountered at one time. Also it's not wise to just blindly enable everything in the audit log without understanding why you're hitting it. Finally, it's possible for denials to occur that won't get logged in the audit log at all (see "dontaudit" setting).

Comment: Yes, thats a fair point. However some applications behave differently according to the status of SELINUX, so just setting it to permissive may also not capture all the denials.

Comment: Had to install audit2allow via: yum install policycoreutils-python on Centos 7

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at /var/log/syslog. That file contains SELinux error messages, which tell you how to fix up any permission problems.

Comment: There is no syslog under /var/log/ could it be located somewhere else or under a different name? I have been looking in /var/log/httpd/error_log that is where I got the error that I originally posted

Comment: /var/log/messages then?

Comment: yeah I edited the question because the response wouldn't fit. but based on that file I still do not know what to do to fix the problem

Comment: I see that your /var/log/messages does not contain sealert messages (which aid in solving the problems). Try this guide to enable sealert: http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux#head-02c04b0b030dd3c3d58bb7acbbcff033505dd3af

Comment: Yeah I just get the error no instructions for fixing it. I read through that page that's how I found out where the log file was but I'll take a second look I guess that's the best help I'll get for this. Thanks for your answers

Comment: It is usually under /var/log/audit/audit.log but that's configurable in syslog.conf. Also not every denial is logged.